# Softbrick after Phone hanging. Rooted but Stock ROM on Nexus 5

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot-loop

I have a really big problem... I have my Nexus 5 for 2 months now and not it doesn't restart anymore.

My phone is rooted and on Stock Android 4.4.2 and enabled developer mode (tapping that 15 times on the build number in settings menu) but I haven't changed that much. And it worked for over a month now. Since the last change in software or settings, the phone was rebooted at least twice.

The last thing I have done was using the app OpenSignal to check my Signal coverage while playing some music over Bluetooth. Because I had enabled that visual feedback for touch, i saw, that my touch on some diagram in OpenSignal was recognized. The Music stopped immideately and the device freezed. Then I tried to reboot it by holding the power key long. The screen went blank.

Then I tried to restart it by holding down the power key long. "Google" appears on screen; screen went blank. Nothing. This is repeatable.

Connecting to a computer shows the "Charging" screen. This is repeatable.

The tried to put the phone into recovery mode. By holding down Vol Down and Power for a quite long time i got that in that mode. than double Vol Down and Power. The screen showed a strange glitch. Like a gameboy that runs out of battery, the lines shifted inside each other. Screen went blank again.

I still can reboot to the Google screen and get the charging screen. I hope it is only a Softbrick and not a Hardbrick. How can I get it working again?

I just have recognized that sometimes after the Google-Logo the system goes to these balls but freeze before the first ball (Red one from left) could be seen completely.

Comment: Did you make a Nandroid backup? `Since the last change in software or settings, the phone was rebooted at least twice.` Did you update something after rooting (other than the OpenSignal issue)? Can you get an ADB connection at all?

Comment: I updated some playstore software. One reboot was because the battery was nearly empty and I shut down the phone to have emergency backup and the second reboot was beaucse I killed some services that drained the battery but started up automaticly. So atfer the reboots the system was totally normal.